# Is there an expository account of homology of simplicial sets that does not assume prior familiarity with any variant of homology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complexes

There are numerous expositions of simplicial homology in the literature.

Munkres in “Elements of Algebraic Topology” develops the homology theory of simplicial complexes.

Hatcher in “Algebraic Topology” develops the homology theory of Δ-complexes, or, equivalently, semisimplicial sets.

Neither formalism is as efficient as simplicial sets:

- one needs 14 triangles to encode the 2-torus as a simplicial complex,
  whereas 2 triangles are sufficient for Δ-complexes or simplicial sets;
- homology of simplicial complexes requires one to introduce orientations on simplices,
  which is not necessary for simplicial sets;
- products of Δ-complexes are cumbersome to develop and work with,
  whereas products of simplicial sets are easy to construct
  as categorical products, whose
  presence further simplifies the resulting theory compared to Δ-complexes
  (e.g., the universal property of products, etc.).

Goerss and Jardine in “Simplicial Homotopy Theory” only spend a few lines defining the non-normalized Moore complex before Example I.1.4.
They also explicitly assume knowledge of singular homology in that paragraph
and do not compute any examples.

Gelfand and Manin in §I.4 of “Methods of Homological Algebra”
give some basic definitions, but they use non-normalized chains
and do not compute any examples.
Greg Friedman's article “An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets” has the same issue.

Finally, there are numerous expositions of singular homology of topological spaces,
but these expositions typically have a different focus, and are not perfectly
suitable for learning about homology of simplicial sets,
since normalization of simplicial chains is not mentioned,
but is crucial for computing the homology of simple examples with simplicial sets, e.g., surfaces, spheres, real projective spaces, etc.

**Is there an expository account of homology of simplicial sets
that does not assume prior familiarity (as a formal
dependence or as a source of intuition) with any variant of homology?**
To clarify, in this expository account normalized chains should be used to compute at least one simple example of homology, e.g., a 2-torus, real projective plane, etc.

Comment: There is the book of Goerss and Jardine, *Simplicial Homotopy Theory*. There are some remarks on singular homology, but they aren't necessary for the definitions: everything is purely in simplicial terms.

Comment: What about Gelfand--Manin's *Homological algebra*? (Maybe it's not an in-depth treatment as other references specifically addressed towards simplicial sets though)

Comment: I am sorry, would you mind pointing me to the exact section in Goerss-Jardine that treats homology of simplicial sets?  I cannot find anything close.

Comment: @Qfwfq: While Section I.4 in Gelfand–Manin indeed contains the basic definitions (which is better than nothing), their definition of simplicial chains does not use normalized chains, which makes it unsuitable for computations with simple examples.  They also compute exactly zero examples of homology.

Comment: @DenisNardin: I was aware of these 5-6 lines in Goerss-Jardine before I wrote this post, but how could they possibly be an answer to my question?  Goerss and Jardine write "Recall that the integral singular homology groups H^*(X; Z) of the space X are defined to be the homology groups of the chain complex ZSX." and assume prior knowledge of singular homology in this tiny fragment.  Normalization of chains is not used, no examples are computed, and they clearly assume prior knowledge of algebraic topology, including homology.

Comment: I edited the question to reiterate the point about normalized chains and simple examples.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Homology is defined on page 5. Then Section 2.2 deals with normalized complexes etc. It's not explicitly about homology of spaces, rather about simplicial abelian groups, but implicitly you can take $A = \mathbb{Z}X$ throughout.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Yes, this is what the question highlighted in bold asks for: "an expository account of homology of simplicial sets that does not assume prior familiarity with any variant of homology".

Comment: Goerss and Jardine explicitly assume familiarity with singular homology in this fragment: "Recall that the integral singular homology groups H^*(X; Z) of the space X are defined to be the homology groups of the chain complex ZSX."  So it could not possibly be an answer to the first version of the question either.

Comment: Try to take a look at [An elementary illustrated introduction to simplicial sets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4221.pdf) of Greg Friedman. It could be very good for your purposes. It misses some explicit computation but it is very clear!

Comment: I am aware of Greg Friedman's article, it is very good, but the only place in it where homology of simplicial sets is mentioned is Example 6.3, which takes 7 lines of text and suffers from the same 2 problems that I pointed out in the main post: it does not use normalization of chains and does not compute any examples.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining how something could exist that answers your questions with all these restrictions in place. You want some reference that only does things with simplicial sets, but then does enough topology to 'present' surfaces with small simplicial sets associated to a cell structure (*not* there singular simplicial set) and then computes homology using the normalized chain complex... but surely any such reference would just use the cellular chain complex (which will agree with the normalized thing from the associated simplicial set) and bypass simplicial sets entirely, right?

Comment: @DylanWilson: I am not sure why this reference would do "enough topology to 'present' surfaces with small simplicial sets associated to a cell structure".  No topological spaces need to be mentioned at all in such a source.  One can draw pictures of small simplicial sets directly without any reference to topological spaces.  There are older sources that do this for abstract simplicial complexes, so the question is whether something similar exists for simplicial sets, which are more convenient.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unfortunally, I don't belive that there exists a such "complete" reference. Anyway, If I remember well also some Milnor's paper could be interesting to you.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I still think that Goerss-Jardine come closest of all available references, even if they are slanted towards homotopy and need the reader to bring their own motivation and examples. At least they provide a logically self-contained treatment of the topic. Unfortunately there is a dearth of introductory books in homotopy theory written from a simplicial perspective

Comment: Hi, did you ever come across something along these lines/write something along these lines that you liked?

Comment: @D.R.: Yes, see Sections 15–24 in my notes: https://dmitripavlov.org/notes/topology.pdf